# adding a keyword without a definition in a Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash, rspec, key

I have the following block which allows me to add whole entries with keyword and definition:

```
class Dictionary

  def initialize
    @d = {}
  end

  def entries
    @d
  end

  def add(entry)
    (entry).each {|k,v=nil| 
      @d[k] = v
    }
  end

  def keywords
    @d.keys
  end

end
```

I want to be able to add a keyword without a definition (add key, but no value).  I tried setting v=nil in the block above, but it still fails.  Here is the error I get when running against Rspec:

```
Dictionary
  is empty when created
  can add whole entries with keyword and definition
  add keywords (without definition) (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Dictionary add keywords (without definition)
     Failure/Error: @d.add('fish')     
     NoMethodError:
      undefined method `each' for "fish":String
   # ./11_dictionary/dictionary.rb:13:in `add'
   # ./11_dictionary/dictionary_spec.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Finally, here is the rspec test it needs to pass:

```
it 'add keywords (without definition)' do
  @d.add('fish')
  @d.entries.should == {'fish' => nil}
  @d.keywords.should == ['fish']
end
```

Comment: shouldn't do a `def add(entry, val=nil) @d[entry]=val unless @d[entry] end` do the trick? or do i not understand the question?

Comment: Thanks, but i got an error when i tried that.  I think the add method only takes one argument rather than two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `entry` can be a Hash like `'fish' => 1` or a String like  `'fish'`

```
def add(entry)
  if entry.is_a? Hash
     (entry).each {|k,v=nil| 
        @d[k] = v
     }
  elsif entry.is_a? String
    @d[entry] = nil
  else 
    raise "wrong input type in add entry"
  end
end
```

You can similarly handle different forms of inputs. For e.g. to handle an array of entries check if `entry.is_a? Array` and then process accordingly.

That said probably a cleaner way of coding this method is to have the key and value as explicit inputs as @steenslag has suggested.

```
def add_key(k,v=nil)
   @d[k] = v
end
```

Then you can call the method like `add("fish", 1)` to add with a value OR `add('fish')` to add without a value.

To add multiple keys define another method like:

```
def add_keys(opts={})
  opts.map{|k,v| @d[k] = v}
end
```

This can be called as `add_keys("fish" => 1, "dog" => 2, "mouse" => nil)`. This notation is along the same lines of `update_attribute` and `update_attributes` methods of RoR.

Comment: This worked!  Thanks.  I'm a newbie so I didn't even know about the .is_a? methods.

Comment: You might consider using a `case` statement here: `case entry ... when Hash ... when String ... else ... end`.  (`case` uses `===`)

Comment: @user2785673 see the updated answer for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

What did you mean by that?

```
def add(entry)
  (entry).each {|k,v=nil|
    @d[k] = v
  }
end
```

Since you pass a single element, the body can be simply this:

```
def add(entry)
  @d[entry] = nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i try this, the test before it doesn't pass (that's the test to accept both keyword and definitions).  It looks like I need to be able to accept 1. empty hashes (which works with my original code), 2. keywords and definitions (which also works),but also 3. keywords only (with no definitions)...

Answer (score 0):

```
def add(key, value=nil)
  @d[key] = value
end
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Hi thanks, but similar to the comment above, when I try that, it fails the prior test which is supposed to accept both keys and values.  I have to find a way for the add method to accept both key-value entries as well as just keys.

Comment: try calling the method like this: `@d.add("fish, 1)` and `@d.add("dog")`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the method can only accept one argument.  It looks like the solution above, using .is_a? method worked.  Thanks again though